# How to implemet singleThreaded=true in TestNG

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, testng

In TestNG i am trying to undertand the use of `singleThreaded=true` attibute of `@Test` Annotation .I already referred http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html and 
http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000407.html but didn't got much help .

My Question : Why do we need to execute method on single thread. Running on multiple thread can save out time.

Note : In the example given at http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000407.html

He said :: "the two test methods `testf1()` and `testf2()` test the methods `A#f1` and `A#f2` respectively, but when you ask TestNG to run these tests in parallel mode, **these two methods will be invoked from different threads, and if they don't properly synchronize with each other, you will most likely end up in a corrupt state.**

Can anyone explain with code the above example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently used this setting because the tests needed so.
Example, we have entity1 & entity2
and we do some operations on those entities, only one operation at a time is allowed on the entities and conflict error is given back to user if user tried to run multiple operations.
To test all the scenarios, tests have to executed one at a time. To achieve that tests have to run in singleThreaded mode.

Updated with an example
Below is a madeup exampe based on real world scenario.
We have devices which collect temperature and humidity. We have fixed number of devices to test in lower environment.
Devices can perform only one task at a time.

```
class XDevice {
    private String id;
}

class WorkOrchestrator {
    public long createWork(Collection<String> devices, WorkTypeEnum workType) {
        if(areDevicesBusy(devices)) {
            //devices are already performing some work
            throw new ConflictException();
        } else {
            if (workType == TEMPERATURE) {
                handleTemperature(devices);
            } else if (workType == HUMIDITY) {
                handleHumidity(devices);
            }
        }
    }
}

class TemperatureHandler {
    public handleTemperature(Collection<String> devices) {
        //handle temperature related stuff
    }
}

class HumidityHandler {
    public handleHumidity(Collection<String> devices) {
        //handle humidity related stuff
    }
}



@Test(SingeThreaded = true)
class XDeviceIT {
    
    //we have fixed list of devices for testing
    private Collection<XDevice> devices;
    
    @Test
    public testAverageTemperatureCollectedFromDevices() {
        
    }
    
    @Test
    public testAverageHumidityCollectedFromDevices() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Kindly elaborate more with some example. As per the question asked the help is needed on HOW to implement. 
It is a great point you highlighted above but missing the how part.

Comment: sure added example in the answer

Answer (score 1):

As is explained here http://beust.com/weblog2/archives/000407.html **...if the classes you are testing are not multithread-safe...**

So your tests can run in parallel, but if you are testing classes which are not thread safe things can break.

In example one test calls `a.f1()` and second one calls `a.f2()`. If these methods uses some shared resources in object `this.a = new A()` and depends on each other **you will most likely end up in a corrupt state** with object `this.a`.

Comment: Thanks! for your reply but that's what i am asking "one test calls a.f1() and second one calls a.f2(). If these methods uses some shared resources in object this.a = new A() and depends on each other you will most likely end up in a corrupt state with object this.a"
Can you please explain by giving an example

Comment: For example if implementation of singleton is not thread save. So you have something like `public static MyObject getInstance() { if(instance == null) { instance = new MyObject();} return instance;}` and you call in both test methods (`testf1()` and `testf2()`) MyObject.getInstance(). Then there is possibility to create two instances because first `testf1()` check for null and it's true. Then context is switched and second `testf2()` check for null and it's again true.