# Is it possible to ensure some particular TestNG tests to run in same thread?

Tags: multithreading, testng

I have tests in my xml file like this -

```
<test name="1. Test 1">
    <classes>
        <class name="some class">
            <methods>
                <include name="some method" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="2. Test 2">
    <classes>
        <class name="some class">
            <methods>
                <include name="some method" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="3. Test 3">
    <classes>
        <class name="some class">
            <methods>
                <include name="some method" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

I am using `<ThreadLocal>` to store some global parameters which I would be using in subsequent tests but the dependent tests sometimes run in the different thread in parallel execution hence I unable to retrieve the parameter in that different thread. How do I ensure that specific tests run in specific thread only?

**Note:** I know dependent tests are not ideal design but it is necessary for me to do that. Also, I can include only 1 method in each `<test>` tag because our internal reporting system only supports the tests to be written like this format in xml file.

One easy solution would be to store the parameters in some properties file and retrieve from there.

Any other solutions are welcome.

There is a concept of [singlethreaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882696/how-to-implemet-singlethreaded-true-in-testng) but that is defined at a class level. I am looking for something similar but with little more flexibility, for example doing that for groups, so that I can club the tests which I want to run in single thread in one group and define that group to run in same thread.

Comment: check if this helps https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests

Comment: @qaautodev No it doesn't help. Can you point out specifically what you are trying to suggest?